# PortProton не запускается на Arch Linux

Tags: linux, archlinux

запускаю с консоли, выдаёт ошибку:

> ls: cannot access '/home/user/.local/share/PortWINE/PortProton/data/dist/': No such file or directory

пытался запустить через plasma x11 и plasma wayland - результат не поменялся